# Is there a free spreadsheet or spreadsheet-like control for Visual C++/ VB.Net?

Tags: .net, spreadsheet

I've been wanting to put together a simple little app that'll let me create simple spreadsheets; just entering data into a grid, maybe with a little basic font/cell/border formatting in there for good measure if possible.

In other words, I want to just slap together the spreadsheet equivalent of Notepad.

Looking around, I can't seem to find any info on a generic "spreadsheet" control for VC++ or VB. I've seen a few 3rd-party controls, but I don't really want to spend $500+ on something just for my simple use.

Does anyone have any suggestions or links to places where I can get info on how to create "Excel-lite"?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [SourceGrid](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/), it's a free grid. It's got a lot of formatting/spreadsheet options, but no formula stuff.

Comment: That's fine, I'm looking more for an easy way to jot down tables more than calculating stuff. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [XmlSS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/xmlsscp.aspx).

Edit: This is rather on the complex side, in an attempt at supporting *most* of what Excel does. If you don't need calculations and such, a [grid control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/gridprojects.aspx) is a lot simpler.

Comment: Looks a bit overly complicated behind the scenes, but I'll take a look. Thanks.